# Dynamically get the values from DataSet using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What I am trying to do is to print the values from dataset on the aspx page using JavaScript.

I got the filled DataSet as:

```
var Total_Record_count="<%=dsExistingTranData.Tables(0).Rows.count %>";
    var DynRowCount=1;

    for(DynRowCount = 1; DynRowCount <= Total_Record_count; DynRowCount++)
    {
        test = " <%=dsExistingTranData.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("CUST_NAME")%>";

    }
    console.log(test);
```

My dsExistingTranData contains multipal data eg: CUST_NAME from the above code i am able to get the CUST_NAME at Row(0).

Is their any way to dynamically increment the value of Row() usning javascript variable  so that I can able to get the other values. I tried

```
var Total_Record_count="<%=dsExistingTranData.Tables(0).Rows.count %>";
    var DynRowCount=1;

    for(DynRowCount = 1; DynRowCount <= Total_Record_count; DynRowCount++)
    {
        test = " <%=dsExistingTranData.Tables(0).Rows(%>"+ DynRowCount +"<%).Item("CUST_NAME")%>";

    }
    console.log(test);
```

is their any way to do this in such simple way..??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use, if this (presumably) is the backend

```
"<%=dsExistingTranData.Tables(0).Rows(%><%="+DynRowCount+"%><%).Item('CUST_NAME')%>";
```

Comment: it says ')' expected. i tried other ways for using ) but stl not working and you used single quots in ('CUST_NAME') which acts as comment..

Comment: try this then ("CUST_NAME")

Comment: I replaced it with " at first , but is says  ')' expected